# Find the unique mapping between elements of two same size arrays

Tags: algorithm

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

There are two arrays of size 'n' each. One array has nuts, the other one has bolts. Each nut fits exactly one bolt and vice-versa. When you compare a nut with a bolt, you get one of the 3 results: tight,loose,fits.

How do you efficiently find the unique mapping?

Sorting is not possible on either of the sets. You never know if b1 is smaller than b2 or
n1 is smaller than n2. Where n1,n2 are nuts and b1,b2 are bolts. Only thing you can do is compare a nut with a bolt and get a result: tight,fits,loose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quicksort like algorithm does the job:

1. Randomly pick a nut `n` and use it as pivot to partition the set of bolts `B` into three sets: tight (`B1`), loose (`B2`), fits.
2. Mark the fit bolt as `b`. Now you use this bolt as pivot to partition the nuts set `N\n` into two set: tight (`N1`) or loose (`N2`).
3. Now you have three pairs: `N1` and `B1`, `n` and `b`, `N2` and `B2`. All of them are of the same size. You can do the same partitioning recursively on (`N1,B2`) and (`N2,B1`) and you can get the final answer.

It is obvious the complexity is `O(N log N)`, the same as quicksort.

Comment: Your #3 is not quite right.  Nuts that are tight on the selected bolt are smaller than that bolt, and bolts that are tight on the selected nut are larger than that nut.  Partition on (N1, B2) and (N2, B1).

Comment: alternatively, just redefine the sets int steps 1/2. instead of tight/loose, use higher-diameter, lower-diameter. Saves some confusion.

Comment: @Jimmy: Though the answer is the same, it is better to denote this way, because people are more aware of the exchange meaning of tight and loose.

Comment: +1, because i want to suggest this, but its complexity is not O(nlog(n)), it's average time is O(nlog(n)) and it's time is O(n^2) (in worst case)

Answer (score 4):

Take one nut `N0` and compare it against all bolts. With the resulting information, we can split the bolts array into `[bolts smaller than B0] + B0 + [bolts larger than B0]`. There is always a unique `B0` that fits `N0` based on the statement of the question.

Then take the next nut `N1` and compare it against `B0`. If the result is "tight", we search the smaller half as we did above with `N0`. Otherwise, we do the same but with the larger half. Doing this will further split one of the two halves into 2.

Continue doing this until you've worked through all nuts. This is equivalent to quicksort. Average case is O(N logN), but there's the obvious worst case complexity of O(N^2) when the list is "sorted" already.

Answer (score 4):

For formal analyses (including quicksort) see http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PUZZLES/nuts_solution.html and http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/05-nutsbolts.pdf