# Average case nlogn Nuts and Bolts matching

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have to make an algorithm that matches items from two arrays, we are not allowed to sort either array first, we can only match by comparison with an item from array 1 to and an item to array 2 (comparisons being <,=,>). The output is two lists and they have the same order. I can think of ways to solve it using n(n+1)/2 time. The goal is nlog(n). I have been banging my head against a wall trying to think of a way but I can't. Can anyone give me a hint?

So to explain the input is two arrays ex. A = [1,3,6,2,5,4]  B =[4,2,3,5,1,6] and the output is the two arrays with the same order. You can not sort the arrays individually first or compare items within the same array. You can only compare items across lists like so A_1<B_1,  A_2=B_3,   A_4<B_3.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Edited

Comment: So A and B have the same elements? Can there be duplicates in each?

Comment: Randomization makes this much easier, if allowed.

Comment: I had forgotten the details, but getting worst case n log n was a research paper in the mid 90s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27722418/2144669.

Comment: Okay I have noted that this is a duplicate question. Interesting that its called nuts and bolts. Ive updated the title

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks. Given that even the "simpler" one's paper has 23 complicated-looking pages, I'm thoroughly happy that I didn't spend time trying to come up with a worst case n log n solution myself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to quicksort:

Use a random A-element to partition B into smaller-B, equal-B and larger-B. Use its equal B-element to partition A. Recursively match smaller-A with smaller-B as well as larger-A with larger-B.

Just like quicksort, expected time is O(n log n) and worst case is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: +1, but note that although this gives *expected* O(n log n) time, it gives *worst-case* O(n²) time: imagine the case where you happen to always select either the greatest A-element or the least A-element.

Comment: @ruakh Alright, added. Didn't find it that noteworthy, as most people are probably familiar with quicksort and its complexities and because the worst case behaviour is unlikely.