# Match same values from two distinct arrays

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, matching

Imagine we have 2 arrays that have the exact same elements (not in the same order) but, as a restriction, we can only compare elements of array A to elements of array B (meaning we can't sort them individually and then print out the result). And the goal is to match the elemnts of A and B and sort sort it in ascending order. So with these 2 arrays as input:
A = [5, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 6] and B = [1, 5, 2, 6, 8, 4, 7, 3]

The output should be like

```
A 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
B 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

The only solution I can think of right now is

```
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = i; j < len; j++)
            if (A[i] == B[j])
                swap(A, i, j);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = i; j < len; j++)
            if (A[i] > B[j])
                swap(A, i, j);
                swap(B, i, j);
```

That would take too long with big outputs though. Is there an efficient algorithm to use here? That makes it faster than O(n^2)

Comment: If you know they have the exact same elements, why would you not just sort one of them and then assign that to both? You don't need to individually sort each list, you know they'll be identical after sorting.

Comment: @LayneBernardo It's a restriction from the exercise. I can't sort them individually

Comment: Ah I see. I've never seen an algorithm like this, but hopefully someone else might have some insight.

Comment: This [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411940/find-the-unique-mapping-between-elements-of-two-same-size-arrays) before, but perhaps not c-specific. The problem is called ‘nuts and bolts matching’

Comment: @kcsquared oooh thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: Not sorting the arrays individually is senseless - you already threw efficiency out the window with that requirement. So algorithm efficiency is irrelevant, just bubble sort away... it's an artificial problem that I doubt you would encounter in real-world applications. Also quicksort/mergesort is not necessarily faster than bubblesort for this kind of data, real world efficiency depends on which version that comes with fewest branches, not fewest "Big O comparisons".

Comment: I could imagine you could let one array serve as pivot values to use when partitioning the other array.